# Didn't find class on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, eclipse

I used a receiver in this code after running and receiving a sms this error is shown. I try some thing. I create new project and add file again. delete bin file. clean and restart project. but It doesn't solve the error. Is there anything that can solve this error. I really cant solved it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="blocker.activity"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity

        android:name=".FirstPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 <receiver android:name=".receiver.SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>


    <activity

        android:name=".Search"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

    <activity

        android:name=".BlockActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".SmsFilter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".CustomAdapter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
    </application>

  </manifest>
```

error:
[image]

property:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

the class for sms receiver:

```
public class SmsFilter extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {




    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])extras.get("pdus");

            if (pdus.length < 1) return; // Invalid SMS. Not sure that it's possible.

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String sender = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                if (sender == null) sender = message.getOriginatingAddress();
                String text = message.getMessageBody();
                if (text != null) sb.append(text);
            }

            Log.i("LOG: ", "sms recived");
            Log.i("LOG: ", sender);



            if (sender != null &&  Search.search(sender)==true) {


                 abortBroadcast();

            }
            return;
        }
    }

    // ...
}




}
```

Comment: where is your SMSReceiver class. I can't see.

Comment: I add it this class. I edit post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check again the name of the receiver and the class name you declared in your manifest receiver.

In in java file the class name is-**SmsFilter** extends BroadcastReceiver

```
SmsFilter extends BroadcastReceiver
```

As you can see the name is SmsFilter but in your manifest file you are declaring it as **SMSReceiver**

The names are not matching. Edit your manifest to something like this-

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.SmsFilter" android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I hope it would help you..

Comment: Oh. I did not notice that mistake. I set <receiver android:name=".SmsFilter" android:enabled="true"> and that works. but it did not block the sms.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. Maybe you have some other problem in your code.